# Can lodash natively pull a list of keys from an object into a new object?

Tags: javascript, lodash

Using the built in lodash functions, is it possible to pass in an object and a list of keys and have the key/value pairs be removed from the object and put into a new object which is returned. An example:

```
var obj = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3};
pluck(obj, ['a', 'b']) // returns {a: 1, b: 2}
console.log(obj) // {c: 3}
```

where pluck is replaced by one or more lodash functions.

Comment: Do you really need the properties *removed* from the source object? That's a somewhat odd requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Yes using [**omit**](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#omit) and [**pick**](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#pick):

```
obj = _.pick(obj, ['a', 'b']); // { a: 1, b: 2 }
```

For the new object:

```
var newobj = _.omit(obj, ['a', 'b']); // { c: 3 }
```

Comment: `omit` only does half of what the OP asked for.

Comment: What's the other half?

Comment: From the question text: *"...and put into a new object which is returned."* (it was also shown in a comment in the code). Which is why I have an `pick` + `omit` in my answer.

Comment: In the the second example `newobj` is the new object.

Comment: Which only has `c`. I suggest re-reading the question, in particular the code comments.

Comment: It's a bit unclear. If the intention is to mutate the original object then this can be done using pick.

Comment: Reading the question for the umpteenth time, my take on it is that the OP was asking if there was a function in lodash that could be used instead of the `pluck` in the example to remove the keys from obj (lodash no longer has a `pluck` function). Maybe the OP can clarify.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think lodash has anything built in for that. You can do it easily enough just with JavaScript native features, though:

```js
var obj = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3};
console.log(['a', 'b'].reduce(function(newObj, name) {
  newObj[name] = obj[name];
  delete obj[name];
  return newObj;
}, {}));         // {a: 1, b: 2}
console.log(obj) // {c: 3}
```

For something more lodash-y, you could combine [`_.pick`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#pick) and [`_.omit`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#omit), but you'd be creating a new object rather than deleting properties from an existing one (which might be better anyway):

```js
var obj = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3};
console.log(_.pick(obj, ['a', 'b'])); // {a: 1, b: 2}
obj = _.omit(obj, ['a', 'b']);
console.log(obj) // {c: 3}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

---

99.99999% of the time it doesn't matter, but just as an FYI, when you use `delete` on an object, on some JavaScript engines that puts the object into an unoptimized "dictionary" mode where subsequent property lookup is much slower than it was in the optimized object. (*Adding* properties to objects doesn't do this, just deleting them.) Again, usually it doesn't matter, but...